# Runtime Error (NZEC)

Tags: java

I have written the following code and it works perfectly fine on my PC but gives a runtime error of NZEC type on Codechef:

```
import java.io.*;

class Main {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader o = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int n = Integer.parseInt(o.readLine());       //Total videos
    int s[] = new int[n];
    int e[] = new int[n];
    int c=0, i=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)            //Start and end times
    {
        s[i] = Integer.parseInt(o.readLine());           
        e[i] = Integer.parseInt(o.readLine());
    }
    int q = Integer.parseInt(o.readLine()); //No. of groups
    String st = new String();
    int noa = 0 , j = 0 , k = 0, z = 0;
    int count[] = new int[q];    //No. of videos of each group
    for(i=0;i<q;i++)
    {
        int marked[] = new int[n];
        st = o.readLine();
        String temp[] = st.split(" ");
        noa = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
        double toa[] = new double[noa];
        for(j=0;j<noa;j++)                   //Do for every alien of ith group
        {
            toa[j] = Double.parseDouble(temp[j+1]);    
            for(k=0;k<n;k++)                //Check for every video
            {
                if(toa[j]>=s[k]&&toa[j]<=e[k]&&marked[k]!=-1)
                {
                    z++;
                    marked[k] = -1;
                }
            }
        }

        count[i] = z;
        z = 0;
    }
    for(i=0;i<q;i++)
        System.out.println(count[i]);
}
}
```

Could someone please help me out with this?
If at all the error is due to the use of the `split()` method, how come I dont get an error on my PC?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very unsafe and is likely to crash as soon as the inputs are not exactly what you expect - here are a few examples:

- you keep calling `Integer.parseInt()` without exception handling = without checking that the calls succeed
- you create arrays with the parsed integer without checking that they are acceptable (you want them at least positive, and probably not too big)
- you try to access `temp[j+1]` without checking that temp's length is at least `j+2`.

Also, as a general comment, you should try to use meaningful variable to make your code more readable - I don't think anyone can guess what n, s, e, c, i, noa, st, toa are...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the vulnerable areas. Will try to re work on dem and den run again...